# How to structure data

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am having trouble deciding how to structure my model.

I present to the user pages with 20 statements, and for each one he marks either "agree" or "disagree".
I need to store this agreements in an efficient way. The statements will repeat themselves, so whenever the user sees a statement he already agreed with, it should be displayed on the page beside the statement. Also, there should be an option to click on a statement and see all the people who agreed/disagreed with it.

So in other words, I will always need to know whether a certain user marked a certain statement. this is a query that will be performed many many times, so it must be as quick as possible. Querying which users marked a specific statement is less common, and it's ok if it won't be so quick.

So these are the options I came up with, and I'm not sure which one makes more sense:

**option 1**: having a UserAgreement object which looks like this:

```
public class UserAgreement {
  User user;
  Statement statement;
  Boolean agree;
}
```

when I display the page, I query for all agreements by user X and loop to see which statements he marked. (Or maybe for each statement query for user + statement?)

**option 2**: the same UserAgreement object as before, but instead of querying for a user X, store all of them in the user object:

```
public class User {
  Set<UserAgreement> userAgreements; 
}
```

when I display the page I fetch all of them and loop through them to see which statements are marked.  will the overhead added here to the user object worth getting rid of the query from option 1? What if I get to 1000x of agreements?

**option 3**: just have a list of agreements in the user object, no need for UserAgreement object:

```
public class User {
  Set<Statement> agreed;
  Set<Statement> disagreed;
}
```

when I display the user, i easily check whether the statement is in either of the sets. But can I query the reverse, all the users who agreed on a specific statement? and again, what if I get to 1000x agreements? how much overhead is it?

**option 4**: any other ideas?

Comment: What is the nature of your statements ? Are they static values set in stone (like legal stuff), or do you need to handle possible new statements ? It can also affect the way you model your data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that if Statement object contains a relationship to a User via a unique id, all of your problems would be solved.

> "so whenever the user sees a statement he already agreed with, it should be displayed on the page beside the statement."

Every time you load 20 statements, if each statement has a, say, list of ids that have agreed with the statement, you could determine if the current user agreed or not based on the presence of that user's id in those lists.  You don't need a boolean here; the presence of the id determines the true/false.

> "Also, there should be an option to click on a statement and see all the people who agreed/disagreed with it."

Again, if each statement has that list of ids that agreed with it, you can display that list linking those ids to something like userName of the User object associated with that id.

> "So in other words, I will always need to know whether a certain user marked a certain statement. this is a query that will be performed many many times, so it must be as quick as possible."

Determined by "List.contains(Object o)" where the object would be the userId and the return value would be a true or false, depending on if that id is in the list.

> "Querying which users marked a specific statement is less common, and it's ok if it won't be so quick."

This is the same as the point above.  Get the list that belongs to a certain Statement and then "List.contains(object o)"